# 'Organize Series Plugin' as muti author feature

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, posts

Currently with organize series plugin author level user cannot manage their own series. I am trying to add feature to the plugin so that author level user can create & manage their own post and admin and editor can manage all series post.

After a little bit searching I have found that that can be done by creating a 'series owner' metadata for series taxonomy and filter by this 'series owner=authorid' to show & manage authors' own post.

For adding meta for series taxonomy I have found some tuts and plugin wordpress.org/extend/plugins/taxonomy-metadata/ and shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-term-or-taxonomy-meta-data.

Now how can I do that?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You can try this: http://wordpress.org/plugins/user-series/ It's a very simple plugin extending Organize Series providing exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest using the [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin instead. You can create a 'serie' custom post type, specifying the appropriate capabilites, which would allow authors to add descriptions, order posts using drag-and-drop, etc.:

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Basic-usage

https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki/Connection-ordering

Answer (score 2):

the plugin creates it's own capabilities to the taxonomy "series" in orgSeries-setup.php
on line 163.

```
$capabilities = array(
            'manage_terms' => 'manage_series',
            'edit_terms' => 'manage_series',
            'delete_terms' => 'manage_series',
            'assign_terms' => 'manage_series'
            );
```

so you can manage this capabilities and allow it to authors form a plugin like:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-role-editor/
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper
- http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members

then you can save the term meta data as an option like this:

```
add_action('add_category ',save_series_meta)

function save_series_meta($t_id){
    $t = get_term_by('id',$t_id,'series');
    if ($t){
        get_currentuserinfo();

        $term_data = array(
                            'term_ID' => $t_id,
                            'author'=>$current_user->ID
                            )
        update_option("SeriesMeta$t_id",'$term_data');
    }
}
```

so when they create a series it will save there id with it as an option

and then you just make user they can only edit there own series like this:

```
add_action ( 'edit_category_form_fields', 'tme_cat_featured');

function tme_cat_featured( $tag ) {

    $t = get_term_by('id',$tag->term_id,'series');
    if ($t){
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $t_meta = get_option('SeriesMeta$t->term_id')
        if ($current_user->ID != $t_meta['author']){
            echo 'you can only edit your own series!!';
            die()
        }

    }
}
```

and you will need your won meta box that will only let them create a series and selcet from there own.